# swift didSelectAtIndexPath doesn't get triggered

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

First of all I would like to describe what actually I am trying to do.
I have two `tableViewControllers` - first one contains a list of bill's numbers and second one should displays the detail information about the bill depending on which cell of bill's number were selected.

In my first `tableViewController` I am using this to get bill's number from the cell and pass it to ***detailTableViewController***:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! CustomBillTableViewCell

    valueToPass = currentCell.billNumberLabel.text
    print(valueToPass)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "billsDetailSegue", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "billsDetailSegue"){
        let detailController = segue.destination as! BillsDetailTableViewController
        detailController.receivedValue = valueToPass
    }
}
```

The problem is that `didSelectRowAt` function doesn't get triggered at all, after cell selection in the first `tableView` only prepare function triggers and It passes an empty value to the next view.

Comment: make sure that your viewController is the delegate of that tableView

Comment: Yes, i've set tableView.delegate = self as a part of viewDidLoad method in this class

Comment: did you set selection styles for the tableView and cell's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you override `didDeselect` instead of `didSelectRowAt`.
And you probably set a segue for tapping on cell.
Disconnect it and connect segue from your whole `viewController`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you set your `UITableView'`s selection styles to `non-clickable`.

Make `UITableView -> Selection -> Single Selection` and `UITableViewCell -> Selection -> Default` or `something` except the `None`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set the delegate properly